# How do we retrieve the passing attribute value in the XPC component runMethod

Tags: tooltwist

In the XPC when we are trying to interact with an external data Source we basically create XPC component  as shown below 
xpc.start("training.getPeopleList", "select");
xpc.attrib("id", "10365");
How do we retrieve the passing attribute value in the XPC component runMethod?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
// Get the attrib using the following
XData input = new XData(elem);
String id = input.getText("//id");
```

You will find a similar answer at [How to execute complex SQL queries for below mentioned scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247554/how-to-execute-complex-sql-queries-for-below-mentioned-scenarios)